# Running Popen under WSGI with Python 2.7.11, ModWSGI 4.4.6 and Apache 2.4.20 returns empty

Tags: python, subprocess, mod-wsgi

I have a WSGI application that does this:

```
p = Popen(["which", "java"], stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()
```

However it returns empty. My WSGI configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my@myserver.com


        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        # Deploy as a daemon (avoids conflicts between other python apps).
        WSGIDaemonProcess formshare python-path=/opt/formshare display-name=formshare processes=2 threads=15
        WSGIScriptAlias /formshare /opt/formshare/src/formshare/extras/wsgi/formshare.wsgi process-group=formshare application-group=%{GLOBAL}

        <Location "/formshare">
                WSGIProcessGroup formshare
        </Location>

        #Output any errors and messages to these files
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/formshare.error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/formshare.custom.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea why? I have tried different WSGI versions and WSGIRestrictStdout Off but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I was starting Apache with su (I use slackware) and under su java is not available. If I loggin with root and start apache then all works fine.